# Hooking up core dump before apport

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, core-dump

I'm hooked up coredump generation for my application on remote Ubuntu system.

I did it with adding into /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern path to my coredumper bash script.

```
"|/some/.../path/my_coredump_collector.sh  %P %p %s %c %d %e %E %t %g %h %i %I %u"
```

This script writing coredump to the file, packing it to the tar.gz archive with generated info file and sending it to my remote machine using scp.

Script should work only for my application and should call default coredump handler for others.

To achive this I stored previous content of /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern with all flags in the variable. For this particular system default handler was apport:

```
"|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P"
```

I make substitution for command line variables with sed to replace **%symbol** with actual value of given variable.

At the end I just call default handler with replaces and piping coredump file content into this handler.

But seems like apport don't wan't to work this way. I can't understand what I did wrong. I provided valid parameters and coredump input.

My scrip looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

PREV_COMMAND="|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P"
WORK_DIR="/path/to/my/script/file"
DESTINATION="username@hostname:/path/to/store/core/dumps"
SSH_KEY="/path/to/ssh/key"

COREDIR_NAME="$6.$1.$8.core"
TIMESTAMP=$(date --date="@$8")

COREDIR="$WORK_DIR/$COREDIR_NAME"

INFOHEADER_FILE="$COREDIR/core.info"
COREFILE="$COREDIR/core.dump"

###############################
## 1 P
## 2 p
## 3 s
## 4 c
## 5 d
## 6 e
## 7 E
## 8 t
## 9 g
## 10 h
## 11 i
## 12 I
## 13 u
###############################

PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed 's/|//g')
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%P/$1/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%p/$2/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%s/$3/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%c/$4/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%d/$5/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%e/$6/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%E/$7/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%t/$8/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%g/$9/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%h/$10/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%i/$11/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%I/$12/g")
PREV_COMMAND=$(echo $PREV_COMMAND | sed "s/%u/$13/g")

if [ "$6" != "my_app1" -a "$6" != "my_app2" -a "$6" != "my_app3" ]
then
    cat | "$PREV_COMMAND" # don't work
    exit 0
fi

mkdir $COREDIR

echo "PID: $1" > $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "pid: $2" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "SIGNALCODE: $3" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "DumpSize: $4" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "DumpMode: $5" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "Executable: $6" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "Path: $(echo $7 | sed 's/!/\//g')" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "Date: $TIMESTAMP" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "GID: $9" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "Hostname: $10" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "tid: $11" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "TID: $12" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE
echo "UID: $13" >> $INFOHEADER_FILE

cat > ${COREFILE}

cd $WORK_DIR
tar -zcf $COREDIR.tar.gz $COREDIR_NAME
cd -

#rsync -av -e "ssh -i $SSH_KEY" $COREDIR.tar.gz $DESTINATION &> $WORK_DIR/rsync.log # rsync don't want work here :(
scp -i $SSH_KEY $COREDIR.tar.gz $DESTINATION

cat ${COREFILE} | "$PREV_COMMAND" # don't work too.

rm -rf $COREDIR.tar.gz $COREDIR
```

I don't want use apport generated coredump for my purposes. This script in ideal case should work on any system wich support /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern with any default coredump handler.

Comment: How can I delete the question? Probably question become useless for other people now.

Comment: Not surely, I suggest to leave open. You should first delete your answer, then you will be able to delete the question. But I think you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in quotes here:

`cat | "$PREV_COMMAND"`

Without quotes, everything work great.